# Using Fourier Series to find formulas for f(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, differential

Given
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}x+1,&-1<x<0\\x,& 0<x<1\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
f(x+2)=f(x),
$$

I am asked to find the formula for $f(x)$ in the intervals
$1<x<2$ and $8<x<9$.

I made an attempt.

I got $a_0=1$,
$a_n = 2/(n\pi)^2$,
and $b_n=-2/(n\pi)$

I'm not sure if these are right, but they gave me:
$$f(x)=1/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[2/(n\pi)^2\cos(n\pi x)-2/(n\pi)\sin(n\pi x)]$$
I don't know where to go from here.

The given solutions are:

$f(x)=x-1\quad in \quad 1<x<2$

$f(x)=x-8\quad in \quad 8<x<9$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why on earth use *Fourier series* for a problem that is much more easily and directly attacked without them? Try it!

Comment: This is the same as defining $f(x)=x$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(x+1)=f(x)$.

Comment: The given solutions come from the fact that the function, as stated, is merely the function $f(x)=x-⌊x⌋$.